# How to save each table in a separate excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was able to scrape all the table data from this url, but I was wondering:

- First, what would be the best way to store this data to apply visualization? Is it in a .csv file or directly in a database?
- Second, if I want to store it in a excel file how can I make sure that each table is equal to a sheet in excel?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jordami01.html'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html')
driver.quit()
tables = soup.find_all('table',{"class":["row_summable sortable stats_table now_sortable","suppress_all sortable stats_table now_sortable","sortable stats_table now_sortable","suppress_glossary sortable stats_table now_sortable"]})

tables = soup.find_all("table")

tabs_dic = {}

for table in tables:
    tab_name = table['id']

    tab_data = [[cell.text for cell in row.find_all(["th", "td"])]
                        for row in table.find_all("tr")]
    df = pd.DataFrame(tab_data)
    df.columns = df.iloc[0, :]
    df.drop(index=0,inplace=True)

    tabs_dic[tab_name] = df
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't really answer that first one. It's sort of your preference and how you're using it and what you're going to do with the visualisations. Store it however you will best be able to access it.

The answer to your second question is to use pandas ExcelWriter. Just make sure to have a unique sheet name.

Lastly, no need to use Selenium here. You can get that first table from pandas' `read_html()`. The other tables that are rendered are actually in the html but as comments. So just use BeautifulSoup to pull out those comments. Dump all those dataframes into a list, then you can iterate through that list to write to .xlsx

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jordami01.html'

dfs = pd.read_html(url)

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
comments = soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))

otherTables = []
for each in comments:
    if 'table' in each:
        try:
            otherTables.append(pd.read_html(each)[0])
        except:
            continue

dfs = dfs + otherTables

with pd.ExcelWriter('c:/test/jordanStats.xlsx') as writer:
    for idx, df in enumerate(dfs):
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_%02d' %idx)
```

If you want to store as separat csv files, just use:

```
for idx, df in enumerate(dfs):
    df.to_csv('jordan_%02d.csv' %idx, index=False)
```